# Average frames to send

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, combinations

I am stuck on a problem.

-- Question Source - Tannenbaum .

Question : An upper-layer packet is split into 10 frames, each of which has 80% chance of arriving undamaged. If no error control is done by the data-link layer, how many times the message must be sent on average to get the entire thing through?

I am not able to think of a solution, the formula given in the solutions online looks like this $$ E = \sum_{1}^{inf}ip(1 -p)^{i - 1}$$
, where p is the probability of sending all the packets without error and in this case, its $0.8^{10}$ and E is the average number of times message has to be sent. I was thinking of a proof using **Bernoulli trials** but got stuck.

If you can provide a detailed solution please do so.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are familiar with "expectation of random variables" and "geometric distribution".

The approach this solution uses is the following: fix $x \in N$ and let's try to find the probability that we have to send the frames exactly $x$ times. In order for that to happen there has to be an error in the first $x-1$ transmissions and the last transmission is successful. Therefore the probability that we send the frames exactly $x$ times is $p(1- p)^{x-1}$ where $p = 0.8^{10}$. Now let $X$ be the random variable for the number of transmissions. Then the value range of $X$ is $N$. Thus by definition of the expectation of a random variable we have $E[X] = \Sigma_{i = 1}^{\infty} ip(1-p)^{i - 1}$.

Consider the problem where you try to find the expected number of frame transmissions (above we look for the expected number of message transmissions):
Firstly, if you only have $1$ frame and the success probability is $0.8$ then you expect that you will have to send the frame $\frac{1}{0.8}$ times (by expectation of geometric distribution). Now repeating this experiment $10$ times yields as value for the expectation $\frac{10}{0.8} = 12.5$. This is also called hypergeometric distribution (waiting for $k$ successes).

Comment: Thankyou for the solution. But I think it will be ${1/0.8}^{10}$ in the second last line.

Comment: One more thing I would like to ask this expectation thinks that all the frames are sent are either success together or fail together. How will I formulate a scenario suppose 4 frames are a success and 6 frames were corrupt? Then I don't have to send those 4 frames once more. I just need to send the remaining 6 frames.  How to found the expectation of such a random variable?

Comment: Oh I actually solved this question of yours in my second approach. I edited my post to make it more clear. The $\frac{10}{0.8}$ should be correct though.

Comment: The solution comes out to be 9.3 which is $1/{0.8}^{10}$. I am not sure how are you adding the probabilities because sending a frame correct is not a mutually exclusive event, you have to take in account what happens with other frames as well.